# Telling the difference between material-ui SelectFields and getting their values

Tags: arrays, reactjs, javascript-objects, material-ui

I have a form that dynamically generates inputs, where one input is a material-ui TextField and SelectField with multiple options. I am having a problem with telling the select fields apart from each other though. In an ideal world I would like to be able to collect the data from both of these inputs and store them as an object (i.e. `{name: Employee, type_id: 1}`), which will become an array of objects depending on how many inputs are generated.

My current code looks like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import TextField from 'material-ui/TextField';
import RaisedButton from 'material-ui/RaisedButton';
import SelectField from 'material-ui/SelectField';
import MenuItem from 'material-ui/MenuItem';
import DatatypeStore from '../../stores/DatatypeStore';

const styles = {
    customWidth: {
        width: 100,
    },
};

class MultipleEntry extends React.Component {

    state={inputs: [], columnHeaders: [], value: 1};

    addInputField(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        let inputs = this.state.inputs;
        inputs.push({name: null});
        this.setState({inputs});
    }

    handleChange(e, index, value) {
        const isSelectField = value !== undefined;

        if (isSelectField) {
            console.log(index, value);
        } else {
            console.log(e.target.value);
        }
    }

    render() {

        let {inputs, columnHeaders, value} = this.state;

        return (
            <div className="col-md-12">
                {inputs.map((input, index) => {
                    let name = "header " + index;
                    return (
                        <div key={index}>
                            <br />
                            <TextField
                                hintText="Enter the name for the column"
                                floatingLabelText="Column Name"
                                type="text"
                                name={name}
                                onChange={e => this.handleChange(e)} 
                            />
                            <SelectField
                                value={this.state.value}
                                onChange={e => this.handleChange(e, index, value)}
                                style={styles.customWidth} 
                            >
                                {DatatypeStore.getDatatypes().map(el => {
                                    return <MenuItem key={el.id} value={el.id} primaryText={el.name} />;
                                })}
                            </SelectField>
                            <br />
                        </div>
                    );
                })}
                <br/>
                <RaisedButton
                    style={{marginTop: 50}} 
                    label="Add column input"
                    secondary={true} 
                    onClick={e => this.addInputField(e)}  
                />
                <br />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default MultipleEntry;
```

So yeah, examples doing what I would like to do would be much appreciated. If you can do it using material-ui components so much the better!

Thanks for your time

**Update**

Here is the parent component

```
import React from 'react';
import MultipleEntry from './MultipleEntry.jsx';
import Paper from 'material-ui/Paper';
import TextField from 'material-ui/TextField';
import RaisedButton from 'material-ui/RaisedButton';
import TokenStore from '../../stores/TokenStore';

const styles = {
    paper: {
        marginTop: 50,
        paddingBottom: 50,
        width: '100%',
        textAlign: 'center',
        display: 'inline-block',
    },
};

class ColumnHeaderForm extends React.Component {

    state = {title: '', input: null};

    changeValue(e) {
        const title = e.target.value;
        this.setState({
            title
        });
    }

    handleInputChange(columnHeaderArray) {
        let input = this.state.input;
        input = columnHeaderArray;
        this.setState({input});
    }

    handleFormSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        let access_token = TokenStore.getToken();
        let title = this.state.title;
        let inputs = this.state.input;

        this.props.handleFormSubmit(access_token, title, inputs);
    }

    render() {

        let {title, input} = this.state;

        return (
            <div>
                <Paper style={styles.paper}>
                    <form role="form" autoComplete="off">
                        <div className="text-center">
                            <h2 style={{padding: 10}}>Fill out the column names (you can add as many as you need)</h2>
                            <div className="col-md-12">
                                <TextField
                                    hintText="Enter a title for the table"
                                    floatingLabelText="Title"
                                    type="text"
                                    onChange={e => this.changeValue(e)} 
                                />
                            </div>
                            <div className="col-md-12">
                                <MultipleEntry handleInputChange={this.handleInputChange.bind(this)} />
                            </div>
                            <RaisedButton 
                                style={{marginTop: 50}} 
                                label="Submit"
                                primary={true} 
                                onClick={e => this.handleFormSubmit(e)} 
                            />
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </Paper>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default ColumnHeaderForm;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well from my understanding you want to handle the TextField and SelectField `onChange` in the same method. They do have different signatures 

TextField   `(event, value)`

SelectField `(event, index, value)`

But you can achieve it easily by testing the third argument for example:

```
handleChange(event, index, value) {
    const isSelectField = value !== undefined;

    if(isSelectField) {
        // do whatever you need to do with the SelectField value
    } else {
        // do whatever you need to do with the TextField value
    }
}
```

Note:
**You shouldn't mutate your state, that's wrong.**

```
let columnHeaders = this.state.columnHeaders;
columnHeaders[e.target.name] = e.target.value;
```

To avoid it you can "clone" the state object and apply the changes there..

```
Object.assign({}, this.state.columnHeaders, {
    [e.target.name]: event.target.value
})
```

Read more about `Object.assign` here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign

**----------------------------------------------------**

**UPDATED EXAMPLE 26/04/2016**

Now you can see I'm just changing the typeId inside the input object (that I found by its id) for `SelectField`s. And almost the same thing for `TextField` - just change the field name..

```
handleChange(inputId, event, index, value) {
    const isSelectField = value !== undefined;

    if(isSelectField) {
        this.setState({
            inputs: this.state.inputs.map((input) => {
                return input.id === inputId ? Object.assign({}, input, {
                    typeId: value
                }) : input
            })
        })
    } else {
        this.setState({
            inputs: this.state.inputs.map((input) => {
                return input.id === inputId ? Object.assign({}, input, {
                    name: event.target.value
                }) : input
            })
        })
    }
}

//Make sure the id is unique for each input
addInputField(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    this.setState({
        inputs: this.state.inputs.concat({ id: 1, name: null })
    });
}

//Binding the ID in the call so we can use it in that method..
<SelectField
    value={input.typeId}
    onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this, input.id)}
    style={styles.customWidth} 
>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! The check helped, but the problem I am having is that the select list isn't updating it's value in the view (so it stays as the default value even when you click on something different), the state of value also never updates, which I can't figure out. Any clue yourself?

Comment: well, those mutations could be the cause of the problem.. did u remove them? Also, what the parent components is doing in `handleInputChange` ?(it seems you are not using anything passed from the parent..) Can u update your code if u have made changes..? @BeeNag

Comment: I removed my code for the handleChange and replaced it with the check you suggested with console logs to check I was getting the correct values. The values are correct but the select field isn't changing. The handleInputChange is there because this component is part of a larger form so the parent component needs to know the values from this part of it!

Comment: can you show how you are setting the values in your state object after the changes..? @BeeNag

Comment: I won't be able to show until tomorrow but I will do as soon as I can

Comment: I have updated the question with the parent component of this one, I should mention that I am using vanilla flux as a framework for the app. I presume that I should move my state changes off the component state and to a store possibly? But I still can't figure out why the select field doesn't work?!

Comment: @BeeNag are u literally using those `console.log`s? Because you do need to handle how you are gonna change the state..check my answer again - will update with an example

Comment: I wasn't using the console logs it was just so I could ensure that I was getting the correct values from each field! Anyway thanks for your help again.

Comment: is it working now? have u checked my updated answer?

Comment: I works really well! However, the typeId in the created object doesn't update until a new input is added. Ideally I would like it to update before this so that I don't send send any null values back to my database when they shouldn't be there!

Comment: Yeah that's what I ended up doing! Thanks for all your help, it's now working like a charm